# jQuery gmaps marker infowindow won't show on start

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have just a simple question about the jQuery Google Maps code.

I've added a marker to a map and the infowindow doesn't show up on start, only after mousehover.

Here is the code:

```
(function ($) {
var map;
var lat = XX.XXXXXX;
var lng = X.XXXXX;
var htmlcontent = 'CONTENT';
$(document).ready(function(){
if ( document.getElementById("map") ) {
  map = new GMaps({
    el: '#map',
    lat: lat,
    lng: lng,
    zoomControl : true,
    zoomControlOpt: {
        style : 'SMALL',
        position: 'TOP_LEFT'
    },
    panControl : true,
    streetViewControl : false,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    overviewMapControl: true
  });

  var marker = map.addMarker({
    lat: lat,
    lng: lng,
    title: 'THE TITLE',
    infoWindow: {
      content: htmlcontent
    },
    mouseover: function(e){
      this.infoWindow.open(this.map, this);
    }
  });

  marker.infoWindow.open(map.self, marker);
  map.setCenter(XX.XXXXXX, X.XXXXXX);
};
});   
})(jQuery);
```

So, this is the part where I have problems with:

```
marker.infoWindow.open(map.self, marker);
```

It worked well, a few weeks (or months) ago.

I will get this error in the console

```
infowindow.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

and this warning

```
Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
```

How to fix the infowindow of the marker?

Edit: I set the center of the marker individually because the popup of the marker isn't centered at all.

Edit2: Added API keys, no error or warning, but the infowindow of the marker won't show up at start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google.maps.Map object is map.map:

**code snippet:**

```js
(function($) {
  var map;
  var lat = 42;
  var lng = -72;
  var htmlcontent = 'CONTENT';
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if (document.getElementById("map")) {
      map = new GMaps({
        el: '#map',
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOpt: {
          style: 'SMALL',
          position: 'TOP_LEFT'
        },
        panControl: true,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        overviewMapControl: true
      });

      var marker = map.addMarker({
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng,
        title: 'THE TITLE',
        infoWindow: {
          content: htmlcontent
        },
        mouseover: function(e) {
          this.infoWindow.open(this.map, this);
        }
      });

      marker.infoWindow.open(map.map, marker);
      map.setCenter(42, -72);
    };
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/gmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: works well! Thank you for this. Didn't noticed that... Do you have an idea to center the infowindow, not the marker?

Comment: That is another question.